# Select dificil con Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Necesito pasar este `select` que me costo mucho hacerlo, a `Laravel` y no hay manera, me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de poner el `query` directo sin pasar cada clausula por las funciones de `Laravel` o si alguien me ayuda a pasarlo estaría bien :)

```
SELECT s.class as clase,s.name as nombre,SUM(a.contador + b.contador + c.contador) as suma
        FROM
        (SELECT spec_id, count(spec_id) as contador
        FROM wow_$region_leadder_2v2_$season
        GROUP BY spec_id) a,
        (SELECT spec_id, count(spec_id) as contador
        FROM wow_$region_leadder_3v3_$season
        GROUP BY spec_id) b,
        (SELECT spec_id, count(spec_id) as contador
        FROM wow_$region_leadder_rbg_$season
        GROUP BY spec_id) c,
        wow_specs s
        WHERE a.spec_id = b.spec_id
        AND a.spec_id = c.spec_id
        AND a.spec_id = s.id
        GROUP BY clase,nombre
        ORDER by suma DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Esa consulta esta mal planteada y realizada tanto en teoría como en practica, por lo que no es viable realizarla, pero se puede usando function($query)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar DB::query y pasale tu consulta.

```
//Preparo la consulta a ejecutar
$query = DB::raw('SELECT s.class as clase,s.name as nombre,SUM(a.contador + b.contador + c.contador) as suma
    FROM
    (SELECT spec_id, count(spec_id) as contador
    FROM wow_$region_leadder_2v2_$season
    GROUP BY spec_id) a,
    (SELECT spec_id, count(spec_id) as contador
    FROM wow_$region_leadder_3v3_$season
    GROUP BY spec_id) b,
    (SELECT spec_id, count(spec_id) as contador
    FROM wow_$region_leadder_rbg_$season
    GROUP BY spec_id) c,
    wow_specs s
    WHERE a.spec_id = b.spec_id
    AND a.spec_id = c.spec_id
    AND a.spec_id = s.id
    GROUP BY clase,nombre
    ORDER by suma DESC LIMIT 1');

//Obtengo el resultado de ejecutar la consulta
$result = DB::query($query);
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Pudistes resolver con ella?

Comment: si funciono, aunque no es muy seguro usar raw según lei, pero pasar esa consulta al modelo de laravel tiene que ser dificil